# How to schedule or join a batch set of changes using IWorkspaceRunnable?

Tags: java, eclipse, multithreading, eclipse-plugin

BACKGROUND

I am developing a plug-in via Eclipse PDE, and I am having an issue with generating too many ResourceChangeEvents while creating markers (a change event was generated for each call on setAttribute(..) and on file.createMarker(..), so I want to reduce all the code to a single change event). Thus, I am trying to batch a set of changes to the workspace using IWorkspaceRunnable.

THE PROBLEM

I want to wait until the workspace.run(..) is finished before returning my variable "MarkerField.marker_" (otherwise I would be returning "null"). For example, if I were using Eclipse's Job manager, I could use Job.join() to make my calling thread wait for the job to complete. So, is there a way to get the calling thread to wait until workspace.run(..) has completed?

```
// Generates and returns a marker given absolute position
public static IMarker generateMarker(final IFile file, final String message, final        String markerType,
                                     final int severity, final int priority, final int start,
                                     final int end) 
throws CoreException, BadLocationException,
    IOException
{
    // Setting up "line" for marker generation.
    final int line = ResourceUtility.convertToDocument(file).getLineOfOffset(start);

    IWorkspace workspace = ResourceUtility.getWorkspace();

    IWorkspaceRunnable operation = new IWorkspaceRunnable()
    {

        public void run(IProgressMonitor monitor) throws CoreException
        {
            // Marker generation code...
            IMarker marker = file.createMarker(markerType);

            marker.setAttribute(IMarker.MESSAGE, message);
            marker.setAttribute(IMarker.PRIORITY, priority);
            marker.setAttribute(IMarker.LINE_NUMBER, line + 1);
            marker.setAttribute(IMarker.CHAR_START, start);
            marker.setAttribute(IMarker.CHAR_END, end);
            marker.setAttribute(IMarker.SEVERITY, severity);

            MarkerField.marker_ = marker;
        }
    };
    workspace.run(operation, null);

    // Check/wait until the thread is finished.
    return MarkerField.marker_; //I want to ensure this is non-null!
}

// Wrapper class to return marker instance in generate marker methods
// Effectively works as a pointer to a pointer
static class MarkerField 
{
    @SuppressWarnings("null") public static IMarker marker_;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`org.eclipse.core.resources.WorkspaceJob` is a special version of `Job` which includes the workspace calls to reduce the number of resource change events. For this you override the `runInWorkspace` method rather than the normal `run`.

You can use `join` if you use this (also look at `JobManager.join` which allows you to wait on a family of jobs and has a progress monitor).

Answer (score 1):

Good question, and @greg-449 has the right answer, but in case someone is looking for something that works with `IProgressService` (as I was), you can just replace

```
IRunnableWithProgress op = new IRunnableWithProgress() {
  public void run(IProgressMonitor monitor) throws InvocationTargetException {
     ...
  }
}
```

with

```
IRunnableWithProgress op = new WorkspaceModifyOperation() {
  public void execute(IProgressMonitor monitor) throws InvocationTargetException {
      ...
  }
}
```

That is: create an instance of an anonymous class extending `WorkspaceModifyOperation` and implement `execute` instead of `run`.  The result is still acceptable as an `IRunnableWithProgress` object.